# Adding a newline in a spool file

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, spool

Is there a way to add a newline in an sql spool file?
I need the file to be structured in a specific way.

'\n' doesn't seem to work and gets printed literally

thanks,

Update: my SQL file

```
-- Prepare blank file
SET NEWPAGE 0
SET SPACE 0
SET LINESIZE 250
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET ECHO OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
SET HEADING OFF
SET MARKUP HTML OFF 
SPOOL OFF

-- Create the Employees file 
SPOOL employees.txt;
SELECT (case GENDER
when '1' then 'Mr.'
else 'Mrs.'
end ) ||' '|| 
LNAME ||', '||
FNAME ||' newline character '||
FUNCTION ||', '|| DEPARTMENT
from EMPLOYEES;
SPOOL OFF;

-- EXIT SQL and go back to the .bat
EXIT;
```

Result would be something like:

Mr. Doe, John
Manager, Finance

Comment: Do you mean just a blank line in the middle of the output? Are you spooling plain SQL, or from PL/SQL via `dbms_output`?

Comment: I'm spooling plain SQL (i've removed the pl/sql tag to prevent confusion)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can embed a newline character using its ASCII code (well, not strictly ASCII, but close enough here) using the [`CHR` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions026.htm), in this case with `CHR(10)` to represent `\n`:

```
SELECT (case GENDER
when '1' then 'Mr.'
else 'Mrs.'
end ) ||' '|| 
LNAME ||', '||
FNAME || CHR(10) ||
FUNCTION ||', '|| DEPARTMENT
from EMPLOYEES;
```

If you want a carriage return as well, append `CHR(13)` (`\r`) too.

As noted in comments, this introduces a blank line between rows as well. The only way to get rid of that, as far as I can tell, is to - somewhat unintuitively - `SET RECSEP OFF`. The new line seems to make SQL*Plus treat the output as wrapped, which you can also see with the `SET WRAP OFF` command or with the `COLUMN ... TRUNCATE` option, both of which suppress the second line.

You might also want to `SET TAB OFF`, and `SET TERMOUT OFF` if you only want the data spooled to the file, not to the terminal.

---

(From before the question was edited with more detail)

If you just want a blank line between the results from two queries, you can use the [SQL*Plus `PROMPT` command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve032.htm#sthref1685), with no arguments:

```
select dummy from dual;
prompt
select dummy from dual;
```

From the docs:

> `PRO[MPT] [text]`
>
> where *text* represents the text of the message you want to display.
>
> Sends the specified message or a blank line to the user's screen. If
>   you omit *text*, `PROMPT` displays a blank line on the user's screen.

You can also look at the section on [formatting SQL*Plus reports](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_six.htm) if you have other specific requirements for how the output looks.

If you have a PL/SQL block that is producing output via `dbms_output` calls you can use [`NEW_LINE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_output.htm#i1000062) to add a blank line between existing output:

```
dbms_output.put_line('some text');
dbms_output.new_line;
dbms_output.put_line('some more text');
```

Comment: Adding chr(10) separates them nicely, but it also seems to add an additional blank line between results. Any way I can get rid of that?

Comment: @Andreas - took me a while to remember that one... you need to `set recsep off`. Answer updated.